# How to download all Datadog RUM data without facing API limits?

Tags: datadog

I'm attempting to download all data from Datadog RUM. I've tried using `curl` along with the official Datadog API, but I constantly hit data limits each time.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.ap1.datadoghq.com/api/v2/rum/events/search" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "DD-API-KEY: ${DD_API_KEY}" -H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: ${DD_APP_KEY}" -d @- << EOF
{"filter":{"query":"@application.id:*****-***-****-****-***** @type:view","from":123456,"to":1234789}}
EOF
```

Is there an alternative method or a workaround to retrieve all data, or at least to increase the data volume I can download each time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more information on what limit you are hitting? Are you getting 429s from the API for hitting rate limits? What is the error message?